# Dequeue in a Priority queue using a Sorted Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, priority-queue, sorteddictionary

I have a sorted dictionary of the form:

```
SortedDictionary<PriorityType, List<T>> dictionary;
```

where PriorityType is an enum class.

Now I am trying to make Priority queue methods but I have apprehensions about whether my Dequeue method will work or not.

```
public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            throw new Exception("The Priority Queue is empty! Dequeuing is not possible!");
        }

        var highestPriorityList = dictionary[dictionary.Keys.First()];
        var topElement = highestPriorityList.FirstOrDefault();
        if (highestPriorityList.Count == 0)
        {
            dictionary.Remove(dictionary.Keys.First());
        }
        highestPriorityList.RemoveAt(0);
        return topElement;
    }
```

Please help me to improve this method!

Note: The Dequeue() method is supposed to Remove and return the object with the highest priority and which is before other elements with same priority.

Comment: Can you not just check before adding element to dictionary if the list has any elements or not?

Comment: Instead of adding logic to your dequeue, why not have an `Add()` that will place it sorted.

Comment: But isn't a sorted dictionary supposed to sort the values automatically in a particular key?

Comment: No, `SortedDictionary` is sorted by its keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I was able to modify the above code to suit my dequeue operation!

```
public T Dequeue()
    {
        var highestPriorityList = dictionary[dictionary.Keys.First()];
        if (highestPriorityList.Count == 0)
        {
            dictionary.Remove(dictionary.Keys.First());
        }
        var topElement = highestPriorityList.First();
        highestPriorityList.Remove(topElement);
        return topElement;
    }
```

Now I can dequeue for as long as I like without the InvalidOperationException which was caused by the missing element in the list after the RemoveAt operation!